# missing sys call_32.tbl for raspbian kernel 4.1.4-v7+

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi2

So I am attempting to install the header files for raspbian kernel 4.1.4-v7+
It looks like they are not available from `apt-get` so I did a google search and found [this](http://www.niksula.hut.fi/~mhiienka/Rpi/linux-headers-rpi/) so I downloaded the corresponding package with `wget` and then installed it with `sudo dpkg -i <package_name>` the installation goes fine except for this:

```
grep: scripts/../arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl: No such file or directory
```

I tried to see if I could find anything for it with `apt-cache` but it did not find anything...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I ran into the same issue today. Do you have a solution for it?